# Javascript state machine

Tags: javascript, state, state-machine

I'm working on a school project and got stuck with the State machine.

Is it possible to set up a state, and depending on the next event that happens  move it to another state?

I tried to check the forum, but I could only find state machine where you only got one option of "moving" to another state.

```
var fsm = StateMachine.create({
  initial: 'inside',
  events: [
    { name: 'openDoor',  from: 'inside',                                to: 'waitingPersonToGoOutside' },
    { name: 'sensorOutsideOn',  from: 'waitingPersonToGoOutside',                             to: 'personOutside'      },


// here i would like to give the state machine an option, if the sensor inside // goes actie, it should go to state inside. But if the outside sensor goes off, // it should say: Person left.
]});
```

Comment: _“you only got one option of ‘moving’ to another state”_ — as opposed to what? Isn’t that what you want?

Comment: "Is it possible to set up a state, and depending on the next event that happens move it to another state" - that is the pure definition of a state machine. What are you asking?

Comment: Basically I'm wondering if it is possible to give it several moving options from one state.